# Can's show one login page after logout

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

My app use frame.

here index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<frameset cols="15%,*">
    <frame src="navigator" name="navigator" scrolling="no" noresize/>
    <frame src="welcome" name="main"/>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Here login controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    /*-
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
    */

    // Login form
    @RequestMapping("/login.html")
    public String login(Model model) {
        logger.info("open_login.html");
        model.addAttribute("appName", appName);
        return "login.html";
    }

    // Login form with error
    @RequestMapping("/login-error.html")
    public String loginError(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("appName", appName);
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
        return "login.html";
    }

}
```

and here result:

[image]

and after success login (show frames)

[image]
When I press button logout then call my custom logout handler:

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomLogoutSuccessHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html");
    }
}
```

But here result after press **Logout**

[image]

But I need only ONE page (login.html, without frames)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add below `javascript` to the `login.html`.

```js
if ( window.location !== window.parent.location ) {
  // We're deeper than one down
  window.parent.location=window.location
}
```

Comment: Not help. Same result

Comment: I have edited the answer. My bad. it was having wrong check. This should work as per https://tommcfarlin.com/check-if-a-page-is-in-an-iframe/

Comment: It's work... but for one second it show on the left frame and after one second it show on one page.

Comment: You need to put this on the top of the file to minimize the delay. This script actually check if the login page is loaded inside a frame and that condition is `true` then it will load the current url to the top of the browser so it exists frames. The delay cannot be removed to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Not help. Same result